# Can I use Murphy's oil soap to remove pine sap from composite decking?

Tags: cleaning, deck, patio

Does anyone know of anyway to remove pine sap from composite decking?  I saw some posts that recommended using Murphy's Oil Soap for removing it from wood decks.

- [How to Remove Tree Sap from a Wood Deck](http://www.howtocleanstuff.net/how-to-remove-tree-sap-from-a-wood-deck/)
- [How to Remove Pine Tree Sap From a Wooden Deck](http://www.ehow.com/how_7312647_remove-tree-sap-wooden-deck.html)
- [Homemade Deck Cleaner](http://cleaning.lovetoknow.com/Homemade_Deck_Cleaner)

However, none of them discuss how to remove it from composite decking.

Is it safe to use an oil soap on composite decking?  Would this also work for removing it off of bluestone patio pavers?

Comment: "Murphy's oil soap" is just a liquid soap made by saponifying oil. It isn't better for wood than any other soap, despite the marketing. (Or so saith the woodworking magazines.)

Comment: I used Goof Off and it only smeared it around

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned pine sap off deck chairs, deck table and cedar decking by first scraping with a plastic scraper. Then I wet a paper towel in turpentine and wipe off the remainder. Sometimes it is necessary to saturate the area to soften the sap so it can be removed by further scraping and wiping with the turpentine.

The deck chairs I cleaned this way had plastic fabric seat material and were not noticeably affected by the turpentine. Of course after using the turpentine I followed up with a wash using warm soapy water to remove any of the chemical residue.

I have every reason to believe that this cleaning technique would with the composite type deck materials. Since there are variations in material compositions it would be wise to check in a small inconspicuous area before committing the whole cleaning procedure.

Comment: I agree turp would be 1st to try, (clean) mineral spirits (many of mine are tinted) would be a close second, if you don't have turpentine on hand.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck getting pine sap off of skin with TechNu (sold to remove poison ivy oil from skin).   It smells a lot like GoJo and similar hand cleaners; one of them may work on your pine sap.   I'd test it first on a hidden area first to be sure it doesn't leave a stain of its own on your deck.

Answer (score 0):

Citra-Solve! Use full strength, but again test first. I use it on everything including clothing to wipe off pine sap. I live under a canopy of white pines that never stop spewing sap. My deck is a mess with old white sap marks. I have not tried it on the really old marks, but it works perfectly on new and almost set sap